# Create super script for textView

Tags: textview, superscript

I want to create super script for desired text selected by user. I found codes for creating super script like:

```
 \u1d50\u1d43\u02b2 for maj
\u1d50\u2071\u207f for min
```

Is there any other way to directly convert string to super script? If no that where can i get the codes for symbols like # and other alphabets.

Please guide me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous approach to create super script by using Unicodes was not much efficient. In NSTextView, there is a function `superscript:` which converts a selected range of text to superscript. You just need to select the text to be converted into superscript and apply the method by passing the reference of your textView.

It was really easy..